# Torsion-free elements in automorphism groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ be the automorphism group of $G$. Let $f\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$. Under what condition can we say that $f$ is torsion-free (i.e. $f^n=\mathrm{id}\in\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ implies that $n=0$)?

Or more generally, under what condition of $G$ can we conclude that $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is a torsion-free group?

Comment: At this level of generality there is probably nothing useful to say. Are you interested in any particular $G$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I am interested in the case that $G$ is equal to reduced free groups $K_n$. Let $F_n$ be the free group generated by $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ and let $K_n$ be the reduced free group, that is, $F_n$ modulo the relation that $[x_i,x_i^g]=1$ for all $i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$,$g\in F_n$, where $x_i^g=g^{-1}x_ig$ and $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is the commutator.

Comment: Even asking for the weaker condition that $\text{Aut}(G)$ has a torsion-free subgroup of finite index can be difficult and interesting. Examples where this it true include $G = F_n$ and $G = \pi_1($closed surface$)$. But each case seems to be different, and I don't know what to suggest for your group $K_n$.

Comment: @LeeMosher, $\mathrm{Aut}(K_n)$ not torsion free; consider $K_1=\mathbb{Z}$, or the symmetric group $\Sigma_n$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(K_n)$ (permuting the generators). I am wondering if there is a way to detect certain elements in $\mathrm{Aut}(K_n)$ is torsion-free.